# Elsarticle abbreviations footnote before other frontmatter footnotes

Tags: footnotes, elsarticle, front-matter

In Elsevier articles, the abbreviations are presented as a footnote that appears at the bottom of the first page, before any other footnote related to the title or the authors.It has no footnote mark.

My problem is the following: If I put my abbreviations in the frontmatter, I get a blank page with my abbreviations footnote, before the first page. If I put it after the front matter, or inside one of the fields, than it gets after the author footnotes.
Code:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
%% abbreviations command (footnote without a footnote mark)
\newcommand{\abbreviations}[1]{%
  \begingroup\def\thefootnote{}\footnotetext{\textit{Abbreviations:}#1}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title}
%\abbreviations{S1, symbol1; S2, symbol2.}
\author{Author 1}
\author{Author 2\corref{cor1}}
\ead{name@adress.mail}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author.}
\end{frontmatter}
\abbreviations{S1, symbol1; S2, symbol2.}
\end{document}
\endinput
```

Output:
[image: output for elsarticle]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elsarticle` provides the command `\nonumnote` that puts an unnumbered footnote on the first page.  Using this you can code your `\abbreviations` as

```
\newcommand{\abbreviations}[1]{%
  \nonumnote{\textit{Abbreviations:\enspace}#1}}
```

and use it within `frontmatter`.  `nonumnote`s are printed before `curnote`s, but after `tnote`s.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\newcommand{\abbreviations}[1]{%
  \nonumnote{\textit{Abbreviations:\enspace}#1}}

\journal{Nuclear Physics B}

\begin{document}


\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title}

\author{Author 1}

\author{Author 2\corref{cor1}}

\ead{name@adress.mail}

\cortext[cor1]{Correspanding author.}

\abbreviations{S1, symbol1; S2, symbol2.}

\end{frontmatter}



\end{document}
\endinput
```